# Facebook Graph API and videos

Tags: php, facebook, video, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to request all the videos associated with a face book account? So I can loop through and echo them to the page. Sort of like getting the json data of an album that has all the images within this album. I have been using [Facebook Graph API for Video][1]

[1]: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/ as a reference.

I have it working for the albums and images so when a photo is added to face book it updates the website. Now I want to do the same thing for the videos.

Any ideas would be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does not appear the Graph API offers access to a list of videos. You would need to use FQL

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

And query the video table

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/video/

For videos owned by a user. Note you'd have to keep track of the last time you queried and limit your query only for videos with a `created_time` after the last time you checked.

Comment: So if i don't keep track of the last time verse new videos? Would I just get repeats every time?

Comment: Correct - you'd get the entire list of videos owned by that user.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions....Why couldn't I just do the call every time someone visits my site and then loop through the video ID's get the JSON data and embed them in the page?  If I keep track of the last time I queried I would have to save that info in a database. I guess I could save the embed code as well so i dont have to do all that over and over again. Is that your though process behind your answer? Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Yup - that would work too, probably better for your needs. My initial answer regarding the created_time was more for if you were storing the video info in your own DB or were querying it not just when the user visited your site. I haven't done web work in years, so I tend to think more like a backend/application developer :)

Comment: Thanks for you help I may try both if it saves load time. But its only a couple of videos.Thanks again.