# Retrieving public videos through Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

We are using the Facebook Graph API to search for Public Posts as per the following query:-

"https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=" sSearchText

We have found that this query is currently returning only public posts related to status updates. It is not returning posts which contain videos. Could you kindly let us know as to how we can retrieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use FQL as opposed to the Graph API. Details on how to query Facebook for video objects can be found at the link below:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/video

See this existing question for more details: [Facebook Graph API and videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711622/facebook-graph-api-and-videos?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: FQL is going away soon.  Do you have an updated solution?  Bounty offered here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704688/search-video-through-facebook-open-graph-api

Comment: This website manages to perform search queries to retrieve fb videos http://www.crowdtangle.com/videosearch. How does it make it?